# How can I connect my PS3 controller? [Resetting, and changing battery doesn't work.]

Tags: ps3, controllers

I had this ps3 controller for a year. Now it won't connect. I plugged in the cable and pushed the PS3 main menu button but unable to connect the ps3. Tried with all the other cables too. I also tried reset button but still no connection to ps3. Then i thought it was a battery that need to be replaced so I replaced it. The result is the same. I dont know what the hell is going with my ps3?

*Also I changed the usb slot to see the result. So far there is none.

Comment: Have you tried connecting your controller to a computer? Have you tried connecting other USB devices to your PS3 without any problems? How are the lights on the controller behaving?

Comment: It blinks. It behaves the same as I plugged into the ps3.

Comment: But does the computer recognize the controller as some sort of device? On a windows machine it would show up under "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Devices and Printers". Picture of controller, post installation here: http://everyday-tech.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/GameControllerDetected.png